# Two variables limit question

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I proved that $f(x,y)= \dfrac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^3}$ does not have limit at origin.
I used two paths test; first I followed the $x$ axis, then I followed $x = \frac{1}{2}(y^2 + (y^4 - 4y^3)^{1/2})$ for $y<0$.

However, I am STILL looking for other solutions other ideas.

Any kind of answer, help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Elliot, thank you so much for your help

Comment: I just cannot understand the second path...

Comment: It is actually f(x,y) = 1 level curve for y<0

Comment: Still don't get it. I don't even try to substitute that value of $\;x\;$ in the original expression because otherwise I'm going to have nightmares. What did you get? I think the limit is zero.

Comment: There should be something wrong with my calculations, but I set the value of the two variable fuction to 1, then try to understand the level curve

Comment: I know what a lever curve is, the question is why you think taking the particular case $\;c=1\;$ will help you to find out about the limit?!

Comment: Assuming the OP did the math right, if you can approach $(0,0)$ along the level curve $f(x,y)=1$ then this shows the limit cannot exist, since approaching along the $x$ axis gives $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the path $(x,-x^{2/3})$ in the open fourth quadrant as $x\to 0^+.$ The denominator of your expression equals $0$ at every point of this path.  Meanwhile the numerator is never $0$ in that open quadrant. That should give you pause. Even if you exclude this path from the domain of $f$ (which you should have done, otherwise you are dividing by $0$), you have insurmountable problems. There is no way around it: $f$ is unbounded in every neighborhood of $(0,0),$ so there is no hope of a limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is actually a shorter approach.

Comment: The function is not defined in a good way. I mean the domain is not given explicitly. Obviously there are some points very close to the origin where the function is not even defined. However, when we talk about limit and the approaching business, we use only points in the domain (the natural domain, the largest possible domain where function is defined as a real number). Can you give a curve which contains the points where the values get larger in every neighborhood of (0,0) ?
(the existence of such curve is clear as you said)

Comment: You could try y= -(x^2 +x^10)^{1/3}.

Answer (score -1):

Use polar coordinates, so your limit becomes

$$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta+r^3\sin^3\theta}=\lim_{r\to0}\;r\frac{\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r\sin^3\theta}=0$$

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with this. This would work if the fraction factor were bounded, but if $\theta=\pi/2$ then it blows up. The OP's original proof holds true, according to Wolfram. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+y+goes+to+0+of+0.5(y%5E2%2B(y%5E4-4y%5E3)%5E(1%2F2))y%5E2%2F((0.5(y%5E2%2B(y%5E4-4y%5E3)%5E(1%2F2)))%5E2%2By%5E3)

Comment: @ElliotG If $\theta = \pi/2$ there is no blowing up. Blowing up occurs near the the curve where the denominator = 0. Also, may I ask how Wolfram could ever show that a proof holds true?

Comment: As r goes to zero and theta goes to pi/2 you get 0 in the denominator. Wolfram can't verify a proof but it is pretty easy to algebraically check and be reasonably confident about the result.

Comment: I realize what I'm saying is not a proof either I'm just (respectfully) not convinced by this answer.

Comment: @ElliotG "As r goes to zero and theta goes to pi/2 you get 0 in the denominator." True. You also get 0 in the numerator. The function is in fact bounded in the upper half plane. Therefore there is no blowing up as r ->0, theta -> pi/2. (You are correct however that the the answer here is incorrect)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. (1) Why **then** is the above answer incorrect? Where is the mistake?, and (2) How to reach *the correct* answer? This, for me and perhaps for the asker and others, is more important than merely knowing what is the answer. Certainly Wolfram Alpha agrees the limit is zero, but I think that program has quite a few bus and this could be one of them. Thank you.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you. As far as I know this doesn't restrict the generality *unless* some "leap point" is either passed on or artificially avoided, and by "leap point" I mean one where, for some definite angle(s) $\;\theta\;$ , the expression is eithed not well defined or undefined. My question is *also* **how** do they know the limit doesn't exist? The asker "says" he proved so by a rather terrible choice of path, yet nothing's proved. In particular, he doesn't say *how* he proved the limit doesn't exist usingthe path he says.

Comment: You have identified correctly the flaw of such an approach: the denominator $\cos^2\theta+r\sin^3\theta$ can be zero for some $r>0$ and $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @user26857 Indeed so. Thank you. I think I'll leave this answer undeleted so that future readers can learn from all this discussion.

Comment: @Joanpemo We are looking at f/g. The zero set of g is a path that approaches (0,0) and f doesn't vanish on this set. Given that f, g are both continuous, that *always* shows that f/g is unbounded in any neighborhood of (0,0). No further work needs to be done.