# How to prove $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{ x^2 + y^3}=0$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I know that the result should be $0$. I tried polar coordinates and got stuck at this:  $$\lim\limits_{(r,\phi) \to(0,0)} r\frac{\cos^2\phi \sin\phi}{ \cos^2\phi + r\sin^3\phi}=0$$

I wonder if I can jump from this to the result (technically there exists a $\phi$ for which the denominator would equal 0) or if this is not a good approach at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

UPDATE I acknowledge that this is a duplicate question but 1) I searched before posting and couldn't find it asked here and 2) once someone linked it I still didn't quite get it. Only on this thread did I understand the explanation. This is my first question here, which might account for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Approach $(0,0)$ along the curve $y^3=-x^2+x^{10}$.

Comment: That seems perfectly natural

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, how does that PROVE that the limit is 0? I thought that if approached along different curves, the limit might not be the same.

Comment: If you approach along the curve I indicated, I think the ratio tends to $-\infty$. By playing around using $y^3=-x^2+cx^k$, you can get various finite limits. So our limit does not exist, and in particular is not $0$.

Comment: I know for sure that the limit exists and is equal to 0, I just don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @Inez: It is possible that your professor's answer sheet is correct. But the *question* would have to be different. For example, the limit is $0$ if we approach $(0,0)$ through positive $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I think this answer by André pretty much settles this question...unless some new, unsuspected-by-now new insight proves otherwise. The question, apparently, is to choose a path so as to leave in the denominator a power of $\;x\;$ larger than the one we get in the numerator. My answer to the linked question is thus wrong, yet it'd be nice to know when and why taking polar coordinates works, and when it doesn't.

Comment: I think this answer is not far from [@zhw.'s answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1739895/121097) in the original thread.

Comment: @Joanpemo: Crudely speaking, we make the bottom go to $0$ really fast. We do that by forcing partial cancellation between $x^2$ and $y^3$. By modifying the $x^{10}$ suitably, we can also get various finite non-zero limits.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you very much. There is another little (hopefully) detail: the function isn't defined whenever $\;y^3=-x^2\;$ , so we must make sure any chosen path doesn't cross this one, I think.

Comment: @user26857: You are right. Amusingly, in a comment, zhw used the same exponent $10$ that I later chose. There is nothing special about $10$, except that it is plenty big enough, and we mostly have $10$ fingers.

Comment: @Joanpemo: The curve $y^3=-x^2+x^{10}$ only meets $y^3=-x^2$ at $(0,0)$. Any $y^3=-x^2+cx^k$ will have that property.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for all the confusion. So if I pluck in these numbers the limit is $-\infty$ and therefore there exists no limit for this?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The calculation is not difficult. Alternately, take $y^3=-x^2+x^k$. Then the bottom is $x^k$. The top is $x^2y$, and $y$ near $x=0$ behaves (for $k\gt 2$) like $-x^{2/3}$. So the top behaves like $-x^{8/3}$. If $k=8/3$, the ratio has limit $-1$. Thus along the path $y^3=-x^2+x^{8/3}$ the limit is $-1$. But you know that there are plenty of paths that give limit $0$. So we have found two paths that give different limits, and therefore the limit does not exist. By changing the $x^{8/3}$ to $cx^{8/3}$, you can produce paths that give various finite limits.

Comment: I chose the $y^3=-x^2+x^{10}$, or more sloppily $y^3=-x^2+x^{\text{big}}$, because it gives a more intuitive feeling of why things go wrong.